# Evaluation of $\sum n a^n$ using telescoping property

Tags: sequences-and-series

> Show that the series
>
> $$\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}n a^n = \frac{a}{(a-1)^2} $$
>
> for $|a|<1$ using the *telescoping property*.

I know how to do this using other methods. But the exercise asks to use telescoping property.

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: I didn't have any idea

Comment: Hint: Multiply the series by $(a-1)^2$ and operate the telescoping simplifications.

Comment: I presume you're meant to proceed as in the first answer [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/30732/how-can-i-evaluate-sum-n-0-infty-n1xn).

Comment: let $S= \sum n a^n ,$ then consider $S-aS.$ You can obtain an infinite geometric series.

Comment: @Siméon I got $(na^{n+2} - na^{n+1})-(na^{n+1}-na^n)$, which remember something telescoping but this $n$ is really messing everything

Comment: @Giiovanna now do it for the $n+1^{th}$ term

Comment: @Giiovanna: express it only with terms of the form $ka^k$ or $a^k$. For instance $na^{n+1} = (n+1)a^{n+1} - a^{n+1}$.

Comment: Hi, this series is derivative of the geometric series $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a^n=\frac{1}{1-a}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the form of the end result, you want to put $\sum na^n(a-1)$ in the form of a geometric series. This can be done as follows:
\begin{align*}
\sum_{n\geq 1} na^n(a-1)&=\left(\sum_{n\geq 1}na^{n+1} - (n-1)a^n\right)-\sum_{n\geq 1}a^n\\
&=\left(\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} na^{n+1} \right)- \sum_{n\geq 1}a^n=\frac{a}{a-1}.
\end{align*}

Answer (score 0):

$$ \sum_{n\geq 1} (a-1)n a^n = \sum [(n+1)a^{n+1} - na^n] - a^{n+1} $$

We have that

$$\sum a^{n+1} = \frac{a^2}{1-a}$$

and

$$\sum [(n+1)a^{n+1} - na^n] = -a$$

applying the telescoping property. Then,

$$ \sum (a-1) na^n = -a + \frac{a^2}{(a-1)} = \frac{a}{a-1}$$

Then,

$$ \sum na^n= \frac{a}{(a-1)^2}$$